# Control/switching of headphone audio

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, audio

I need to do some simple line control of audio out from a phone, 3.5mm TRS. I would have preferred to use transistors, but the voltage drop on an already fairly weak signal makes it unusable. Also not sure about negative voltage from collector to emitter. Essentially I need to switch the line on/off. How can I do this while not introducing noise or signal loss (K.I.S.S.) - I haven't checked if optocouplers are without voltage drop, but in any case they're probably overkill. 
Ask for clarification if needed.

Comment: This might be of interest to you: http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-088.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settled on a CMOS bilateral switch (4002). Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was what about relays.  I've done a quick search and found this http://www.geofex.com/article_folders/relays/relays_for_switching_audio_signa.htm and this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110750/is-it-possible-to-turn-an-audio-signal-on-off-using-a-solid-state-relay so maybe it's not such a stupid idea, but like optocouplers it probably is a bit OTT.